# Add a column with values via script in Qlikview

Tags: append, qlikview

I would like to add a column with values to an existing table in Qlikview, with no KeyValues between them.

These are the columns of table 1

`Column1 | Column2|`
`1           Q`
`2           Z`
`3           T`

This is the column I want to append from table2, to table 1

`Column3|`
`ret`
`ret`
`ret`

This is how it should look like after appending

`Column1 | Column2| Column3 |`
`1           Q       ret`
`2           Z       ret`
`3           T       ret`

Comment: What is the Relation between the tables if the have nö common keyValue? Order? (and where is the part about summing the values, you mentioned in the other question?)

Comment: None. I just want to insert column3 into table 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to append this:
join load "ret" as column3 autogenerate 1;